# addClass if in Viewport

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, css-animations, viewport

I currently have a piece of jQuery that adds a css animation class to a div when its a certain distance from the top of the page. This jQuery doesnt translate well to mobile. I'm wondering if theres a way to add the class when the div is visible on the page(viewport) so that it works well across all devices.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#about-image-1').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+600) {
            $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked great:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
$( "#about-image-1" ).each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    isOnView = isElementVisible($(this));
    if(isOnView && !$(this).hasClass('fadeIn')){
        $(this).addClass('fadeIn');
        startAnimation($(this));
    }
});
});
```